# How to convert RenderEffect to bitmap or file object

Tags: android, render, background-process, android-workmanager

I have been working on RenderEffect API which was introduced in Android 12 for perform blur, color filter on view efficiently.

I'm able to apply blur effect using RenderEffect API when app launch, with following code

```
fun createBlurEffect(radiusX: Float, radiusY: Float,shader: Shader.TileMode = Shader.TileMode.MIRROR ): RenderEffect {
    return RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(radiusX, radiusY, shader)
}
```

and in compose file with help of asComposeRenderEffect function blur effect is visible on screen.

```
Image(
      modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxWidth()
             .height(height = MaterialTheme.spacing.dp_300)
             .graphicsLayer {
                    renderEffect = imageRenderEffect?.asComposeRenderEffect()
                    clip = true
             },
             painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_dog),
             contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
             contentDescription = null,
)
```

Now I'm looking for apply this effect through WorkManager API, but now I'm not getting any option to convert this blur effect to Bitmap or File, to send back to in WorkManager Result.Success method as data.